# Error when trying to return a 2d array

Tags: java, return, character-arrays

Trying to return a 2D array from a class in Java. We're trying to fill a 2D array with characters from a text file, using two for loops. Filling the array is easy, but returning it to the main class is where we keep getting an error. Getting an error on the return line. Here's the class in question.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReadMe {

    private Scanner lev;
    char[][] grid1 = new char[576][1024];

    public void openfile(){
        try{
            lev = new Scanner(new File("D:\\Jeeeva\\Workspace\\GIANT PROJECT NAME GOES HERE\\src\\level.txt")); //opens file
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error: Level file not found");
        }
    }

    public char[][] readfile(){ //may need some parameters

        while (lev.hasNext()){

        for (int s=0; s<576; s++){
            String line = new String(lev.next());

            for (int d=0; d<1024; d++){

                grid1[s][d] = line.charAt(d);

            }
        }


        }

        return grid1[][];
    }



    public void closefile(){ //closes file after its done reading
        lev.close();
    }

}
```

And here is the main class

```
public class main extends JFrame{

        ReadMe levelx = new ReadMe();
        levelx.openfile();

        char[][] grid = levelx.readfile();

        levelx.closefile();



    }
```

Very green, sorry if this is a noob question.

Comment: `return grid1[][];` must be `return grid1;`. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Change your

```
return grid1[][]; //invalid syntax
```

for

```
return grid1;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid syntax:

```
return grid1[][];
```

try

```
return grid1;
```

Answer (score 0):

After you instantiate an array, you only need to refer to it by its name when you're passing it around and returning it. So, all you need is this:

```
return grid1;
```